# Missing semicolon on SQL call when present

Tags: sql, vb.net

I am attempting to write multiple records to a dbase 3 file and receive an error saying I need a semicolon when I already have one present.

```
SQLCreateCommand = "CREATE TABLE Test (Val1 TEXT(5), Val2 TEXT(5))"
    SQLCreateCommand = SQLCreateCommand.Replace("'", "")

    Dim dBaseCommand2 As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(SQLCreateCommand, dBaseConnection)
    dBaseCommand2.ExecuteNonQuery()

    SQLCreateCommand = "INSERT INTO test (Val1,Val2) VALUES ('Joe','Joe'),('Jim','Jim');"
    dBaseCommand2.CommandText = SQLCreateCommand
    dBaseCommand2.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

This is my test code, the bulk of this is to take a datatable and turn it into a dbf file, but this is the test lines to try and write more than one line at a time (attempted speed improvement).

EDIT: the replace command is leftover code from another part of the project, was supposed to stay commented out from a copy/paste.

The error for the missing semicolon only happens on the second line to insert the records, the program has no issues with creating the table without a semicolon.

Comment: What is this about: `SQLCreateCommand.Replace("'", "")`? Looks like a **very** wrong way to account for query parameters.

Comment: Also: the 2nd statement has a semi-colon. The first does not.

Comment: It seems like it would be possible for the calls to occur in reverse order as well.  the DB engine will determine which SQL to execute first.  First in doesn't always mean first executed.  So the insert may be attempted before the create...

Comment: The commands happen in order, I have them call each time with "executenonquery()"

Comment: multiple record insert is supported by SQL Server 2008. What database are you using?

Comment: This is going into a dbase 3 file.

Dim dBaseConnection As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & "Data Source=" & DataBasePath & ";" & "Extended Properties=dBase III")

Answer (score 0):

It looks like in your insert statement you are trying to insert 2 records at once.  You can't do this with INSERT INTO ... VALUES ...  You need to split it into two statements.

```
INSERT INTO test (Val1,Val2) VALUES ('Joe','Joe');
INSERT INTO test (Val1,Val2) VALUES ('Jim','Jim');
```

Comment: Why not? According to SQL i should be able to with "insert into ... values (set1),(set2)

Comment: @KnightsOfTheRoun The OP states he is using dBase III.  I tried googling it and I can't find anything that says that dBase III supports that.  If it does I would be happy to be proven wrong.

Comment: I already have it running a single record at a time. My issue is trying to add multiple records in one ExecuteNonQuery() for speed improvement. If you have any suggestions on speed improvement I would greatly appreciate it. I am currently running 100k records from a CSV file into a datatable at about 5 seconds, but then outputing that datatable into a dbf (this process i've shown w/ some looping) takes about 8 minutes for 100k records.

Comment: @KnightsOfTheRoun I'm not very familiar with dBase.  I believe (mostly guessing) that you should be able to separate both of those statements with semicolons and send them as one command.  Trying to combine a ton of those commands might cause you to hit size limits on what the database will take for a single command.  You may want to ask this over on [codereview.stackexchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: This answer did not deserve the downvote.  And @KnightsOfTheRoun, don't change the question.  Your question didn't ask anything about 100k records, etc.

Comment: @LarsTech I'm not trying to change the question. I am trying to explain reasoning behind my question. If the big picture gives someone an idea that could save me fixing this question, I would gladly revamp my project.